# AngularJS Directive for looking in associative array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm trying to make an AngularJS directive which from a key mentionned as attribute of the directive should return a template of html containing the string corresponding of an associative array contained by scope data.

I think that codes snippets will be more clear :

My associative array in the scope:

```
{"mapData":
    {"menu1":"Apples",
    "menu2":"Strawberries"}}
```

How the directive will be call :

```
<div ng-controller="menuAngularController">
    <menu-dir menuData="menu1"></menu-dir>
</div>
```

HTML that should be returned after angular-interpretation:

```
<li dropdown class='dropdown dropdown-fw'>
     <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' dropdown-toggle>Apples 
            <span class='caret'></span>
     </a>
     <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu' ng-transclude></ul>
</li>
```

The directive that i'm working on, with no convincing results :

```
angular.module('Module.Directives',[]).directive('menuDir', function(){
    restrict:'E',
     ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶c̶l̶u̶d̶e̶ transclude:true,
    replace:true,
    scope:{
         menuData:'@'
    },
    template :"<li dropdown class='dropdown dropdown-fw'><a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' dropdown-toggle>"+ 
            "{{test}} <span class='caret'></span></a>"+
            "<ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu' ng-transclude></ul></li>",

    link:function(scope, elem, attrs, controllers ̶,̶ ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶ ) {
        //I put $watch because my AngularJS controller load data from an external service, so I listen change on data loaded
        scope.$watch('menuData', function(newValue, oldValue){
                //I get the data of the array by the id
                scope.test = "{{mapData['"+newValue+"']}}";
       });
   });
```

The angular controller :

```
angular.module('MenuAngular.Controller', [])
.controller('menuAngularController', MenuAngularController);    
    MenuAngularController.$inject = ['menuAngularServices', '$scope'];
    function MenuAngularController(menuAngularServices, $scope){
        //the service (tested, all is ok on this side) that return the data on a map
        menuAngularServices.initMenu.query({},function(data){
            $scope.mapData= data.mapMessages;
        },
        function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Actually, I succeed to get "{{mapData[menu1]}}" printed on screen, but not replaced by the value by Angular.

Does anyone have an idea ? 
(sorry for my english level, thanks you in advance!)

Comment: Assuming you have mapData somewhere in the directive (I don't see it in there), you can try scope.test = mapData[newValue];

Comment: I edit my post to add the code of the controller. The value is on $scope (parent scope), not on scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directive attributes need be normalized to `kebab-case`:

```
<!-- ERRONEOUS
<div ng-controller="menuAngularController">
    <menu-dir menuData="menu1"></menu-dir>
</div>
-->

<!-- BETTER -->
<div ng-controller="menuAngularController">
    <menu-dir menu-data="menu1"></menu-dir>
</div>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)

---

## Update

Because the directive uses **isolate** scope, the directive scope does not inherit data from the parent scope. All data from parent scope must be defined with bindings:

```
<menu-dir menu-data="menu1" map-data="mapData"></menu-dir>
```

Also there is no need to use a watcher, simply put the Angular Expression in the directive template:

```
app.directive('menuDir', function(){
    restrict:'E',
    transclude:true,
    //replace:true, //REPLACE is DEPRECATED

    scope: {
         menuData:'@',
         //ADD mapData one-way binding
         mapData: '<'
    },
    //ADD {{test}} expression to template
    template: `
        <li dropdown class='dropdown dropdown-fw'>
           <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' dropdown-toggle> 
            {{mapData[menuData]}} <span class='caret'></span>
           </a>
           <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu' ng-transclude></ul>
        </li>`,

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        //I put $watch because my AngularJS controller load data from an external service, so I listen change on data loaded
        /* REMOVE watcher
        scope.$watch('menuData', function(newValue, oldValue){
                //I get the data of the array by the id
                scope.test = "{{mapData['"+newValue+"']}}";
       });*/
    }
});
```

Comment: I correct it in my code, the error stay the same on screen

Comment: There is no way to have only one reference of mapData to apply for all directives? That will allow to avoid a redoundant precision of the mapdata that will be the same on each directive...

Comment: It is not wise to hardcode and hide connections. It makes the app more difficult to understand, debug, and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

**First thing:** pass `$scope.mapData` inside directive

view:

```
<menu-dir menu-data="menu1" map-data="mapData"></menu-dir>
```

directive:

```
scope:{
     menuData: '@',
     mapData: '='
},
```

**Second thing:** change the `scope.test` assignement:

`scope.test = "{{mapData['"+newValue+"']}}"` is the assignment to create a `string`. Infact this is what you see!

You simply do: `scope.test = menuData[newVal];`

Comment: That will work, but i would prefer to access to the scope of the controller, like a general thing. Because the mapData is the same for all menu-dir...

Comment: When you pass `mapData` in directive, you pass it with two way data binding (`mapData: '='`). With this thing you have that same controller object in directive. Like this you have a general thing ;)

Comment: Yes, but if I have 100 menu element, i will have to indicate 100 times mapData="mapData" whereas it is a generic data obtained by the service in the controller that managed all the menu.

Comment: @MatteoCalvani Directive attributes need be normalized to `kebab-case`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization).

Comment: @georgegeawg i know it but i didn't see the error before. Thanks